# Custom heading with prefix and counter in KOMA class

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, counters

I would like to introduce a new heading in a KOMA-Script class on the subsection level that has a prefix and a separate counter, eg. GP1, GP2, etc. Otherwise, the style should be the same as `\subsection`. `\subsection` itself should not be affected so it can be used in parallel.

As seen in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68551), it is possible to define a heading with prefix based on section (or subsection), but it does not create a new counter and the prefix does not appear in ToC.

It seems that `\DeclareSectionCommand` (see [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273509)) is the proper way to define a new heading, however, I cannot manage to add a prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was not too far away from the solution:

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[
    afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
    beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
    font=\usekomafont{subsection},
    indent=0pt,
    level=2,
    tocindent=3.8em,
    toclevel=2,
    tocnumwidth=3.2em,
    tocstyle=section,
    counterwithin=section,
    style=section
]{gp}
```

All I needed for the prefix:

```
\renewcommand*{\thegp}{GP\arabic{gp}}
```